# MVC View Viewmodel HttpPost returns NULL

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

For some reason my passed ViewModel returns NULL in the controller on HttpPost, but I can't figure out why. I thought I bounded the model in the view with @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => product.Id).

My view:

```
@model MaterialOrderFinal.Models.ProductViewmodel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Result", "Product", FormMethod.Post))
{
    foreach (var category in Model.ProductCategories)
    {
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" href="@($"#collapse{category.Id}")">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => category.Name)
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="@($"collapse{category.Id}")" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">

                    @foreach (var product in Model.Products.Where(product => product.ProductCategoryId == category.Id))
                    {
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => product.Name) <br />
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => product.Description)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => product.Id)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => product.Name)
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                @Html.RadioButtonFor(modelItem => product.Quantity, 0, new { Name = product.Id, id = product.Id }) <span>0</span> <br />
                                @Html.RadioButtonFor(modelItem => product.Quantity, 50, new { Name = product.Id, id = product.Id }) <span>50</span> <br />
                                @Html.RadioButtonFor(modelItem => product.Quantity, 100, new { Name = product.Id, id = product.Id }) <span>100</span> <br />
                                @Html.RadioButtonFor(modelItem => product.Quantity, 200, new { Name = product.Id, id = product.Id }) <span>200</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" />
}
```

My controller:

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    private MaterialOrderContext db = new MaterialOrderContext();

    // GET: Product
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var products = db.Products.Include(p => p.ProductCategory).ToList();
        var productCategories = db.ProductCategories.ToList();
        var viewModel = new ProductViewmodel { Products = products, ProductCategories = productCategories };
        return View(viewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Result(ProductViewmodel viewModel)
    {
        var products = viewModel.Products;
        Debug.WriteLine(products.ToString()); // Returns NULL here!
        return View(products);
    }
}
```

My viewmodel:

```
public class ProductViewmodel
{
    public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ProductCategory> ProductCategories { get; set; }
}
```

The initial website with my categories and products is displayed, but once I click the submit button I get a NullReferenceError.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create the input fields manually and set the `name` attribute accordingly:

```
<input name="Products[0].Name" />
<input name="Products[0].Id" />

<input name="Products[1].Name" />
<input name="Products[1].Id" />
```

Try this code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Result", "Product", FormMethod.Post))
{
    int index = 0;

    foreach (var category in Model.ProductCategories)
    {
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" href="@($"#collapse{category.Id}")">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => category.Name)
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="@($"collapse{category.Id}")" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    @foreach (var product in Model.Products.Where(product => product.ProductCategoryId == category.Id))
                    {
                        <input type="hidden" name="Proucts[@index].Id" value="@product.Id" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="Proucts[@index].Name" value="@product.Name" />

                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => product.Name) <br />
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => product.Description)
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                <input type="radio" name="Products[@index].Quantity" value="0" /> <span>0</span> <br />
                                <input type="radio" name="Products[@index].Quantity" value="50" /> <span>50</span> <br />
                                <input type="radio" name="Products[@index].Quantity" value="100" /> <span>100</span> <br />
                                <input type="radio" name="Products[@index].Quantity" value="200" /> <span>200</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        index++;
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" />
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Solved the error and the selected products are shown on the result page. Problem now is that radio buttons of different categories seem to group with each other and if I select a button for a product of a different category the other one disappears. https://imgur.com/a/akV2hpD
Any ideas?

Comment: @snowcat most probably duplicates of `[0]` indexes. I updated to code (i moved the `index = 0` out). Check now please

Comment: Happy I could help :)